# c++ - How to lock multiple mutexes with high priority over single lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

For example:

```
myClass objects[ARR_SIZE];
std::mutex mtx[ARR_SIZE];
```

My threads mostly access only to one object in array, so I made identical array of mutexs. But sometimes need access to all objects. This is hi-important operation. As far I know mutex don't care for FIFO so it can look like:

```
THR1 -> lock mtx[6]
THR2 -> lock mtx[3]
THR3 -> wait to lock mtx[all] (hi important)
THR1 -> unlock mtx[6]
THR1 -> lock mtx[2]
THR2 -> unlock mtx[3]
THR2 -> lock mtx[1]
...
```

Threads do jobs from external source in loop. When one of them get high-important job which must use full array, other threads must finish actually job and wait with start next job (only if next job need to access one of array value) while hi important job was finished. How to do it?

Comment: The problem here is that if you ask ten C++ developers what is the "best" way to do <X> you are guaranteed to get at least fifteen different answers. Can you reframe your question so that it can be answered with facts and citations, rather than opinions. We do not allow for opinion-based answers on Stackoverflow.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock

Comment: You might want to look at a reader/writer lock instead. This many synchronization primitives is going to bite you back one day. (deadlocks) 
https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/reader-writer-locks

Comment: Are you okay with implementation-dependent behavior (a lot of implementations will queue all future shared lock attems behind unique lock attempt, but this is not guaranteed, for example)

Comment: Do single-item threads need to notice the that there is a pending high important operation, and gracefully abort prematurely ASAP?

Comment: You might wish to consider `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: Locks do not support priorities: the OS can wake up any thread it want regarding the state of the scheduler. Condition variable can be useful to better control this. Atomics can be even better if you could write a lock-free implementation (hard).

Comment: I second what @PepijnKramer said, Use a [readers/writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) (a.k.a., "shared lock") for the global array access. A thread that wants to lock the whole array does so as a "writer." A thread that wants to lock an individual member first locks the global array as a "reader," and then it locks the specific member mutex. The reader/writers lock will allow any number of "reader" locks at one time, or it will allow exactly one "writer" lock, but it will not allow a "reader" and a "writer" at the same time.

Comment: See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex. Call `my_shared_mutex.lock_shared()` to place a "reader" lock, or call `my_shared_mutex.lock()` to place a "writer" lock.

Comment: @SolomonSlow It sounds good, but for example thread1 call write lock when thread2 and thread3 have shared lock. And eg thread3 unlock shared and it want again shared lock (before thread2 unlock). Is thread3 get that lock or must wait while thread1 unlock they write lock?

Comment: I don't know specifically about C++ `std::shared_mutex`, but other implementations of shared/exclusive (readers/writer) locks that I have encountered in other languages try to prevent "shared" clients from starving out "exclusive" clients and vice versa. E.g., If some thread W is waiting for exclusive access, while threads A, B, and C have shared access; and if some thread R asks for shared access, R will be blocked until after thread W has had its turn.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes exactly that :)